# Tkinter: Button hover highlight doesn't work until I manually <Enter> then <Leave> then <Enter>

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button

When I hover over my tkinter buttons, they are supposed to highlight by changing the background.  It works, but only after I manually Enter then Leave then Enter each button.

My actual program has 100+ buttons and I don't want the user to have to hover over all of them before the hover highlighting starts to work!

Here's my simplified code:  How can I make the hovering work the FIRST time?

```
from tkinter import *

DEFAULT_BG = "#AAAAAA"
DEFAULT_FG = "#000000"
DEFAULT_BG_HIGHLIGHT = "#DDDDDD"
all_cards = ["Button0", "Button1", "Button2", "Button3"]
all_buttons = []

main_window = Tk()
main_window.geometry("+20+20")

button_window = Toplevel()
button_window.geometry("+200+20")


def mouse_highlight_enter(e):
    print("mhe" + str(e.widget))
    e.widget['background'] = DEFAULT_BG_HIGHLIGHT


def mouse_highlight_leave(e):
    print("mhl" + str(e.widget))
    e.widget['background'] = DEFAULT_BG


for i in range(0, 4):
    all_buttons.append(Button(button_window,
                              text=all_cards[i],
                              font=("Comic Sans", 8, "bold"),
                              fg=DEFAULT_FG,
                              bg=DEFAULT_BG,
                              activeforeground=DEFAULT_FG,
                              activebackground=DEFAULT_BG,
                              relief=FLAT,
                              state=ACTIVE))
    all_buttons[i].pack()

    all_buttons[i].bind("<Enter>", mouse_highlight_enter)
    all_buttons[i].bind("<Leave>", mouse_highlight_leave)
    # all_buttons[i].event_generate("<Enter>")
    # all_buttons[i].event_generate("<Leave>")
    # all_buttons[i].update()

Button(main_window,
       text="Irrelevant Button",
       font=("Comic Sans", 8, "bold"),
       fg=DEFAULT_FG,
       bg=DEFAULT_BG,
       activeforeground=DEFAULT_FG,
       activebackground=DEFAULT_BG,
       relief=RAISED,
       state=ACTIVE).pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: You aren't preventing the default hovering behavior. Maybe that is part of the problem. Have you tried adding `return "break"` at the end of your functions that are called from the binding?

Comment: @Brian Oakley:  Thanks for your reply.  I did try the return "break" thing, but it didn't seem to work.  I'm somewhat new to Python, so maybe I didn't do it right.

Comment: Since first posting this question, I've been working on other aspects of my program.  This issue still isn't solved for me.  Could someone kindly post a version of my code that works?  i.e. hovering works right away.   Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here. Remove these two lines:

```
activeforeground=DEFAULT_FG,
activebackground=DEFAULT_BG,
```

In both the windows, change the button state to NORMAL. And in the functions, change the bg to DEFAULT_BG instead of DEFAULT_BG_HIGHLIGHT

```
state=NORMAL
e.widget['background'] = DEFAULT_BG #in functions
```

The reason is, button hovering is triggered by a function. But activeforeground and active background override the background insisted by the function.

And by default, is the button state is active and bg & fg colors triggered by the function are also similar to that of active, There won't be any change in color while hovering.

So,, the complete code after correction is:

```
from tkinter import *

DEFAULT_BG = "#AAAAAA"
DEFAULT_FG = "#000000"
DEFAULT_BG_HIGHLIGHT = "#DDDDDD"
all_cards = ["Button0", "Button1", "Button2", "Button3"]
all_buttons = []

main_window = Tk()
main_window.geometry("+20+20")

button_window = Toplevel()
button_window.geometry("+200+20")


def mouse_highlight_enter(e):
    print("mhe" + str(e.widget))
    e.widget['background'] = DEFAULT_BG


def mouse_highlight_leave(e):
    print("mhl" + str(e.widget))
    e.widget['background'] = DEFAULT_BG


for i in range(0, 4):
    all_buttons.append(Button(button_window,
                              text=all_cards[i],
                              font=("Comic Sans", 8, "bold"),
                              fg=DEFAULT_FG,
                              bg=DEFAULT_BG,
                             
                             
                              relief=FLAT,
                              state=NORMAL))
    all_buttons[i].pack()

   
    all_buttons[i].bind("<Enter>", mouse_highlight_enter)
    all_buttons[i].bind("<Leave>", mouse_highlight_leave)
    # all_buttons[i].event_generate("<Enter>")
    # all_buttons[i].event_generate("<Leave>")
    # all_buttons[i].update()



Button(main_window,
       text="Irrelevant Button",
       font=("Comic Sans", 8, "bold"),
       fg=DEFAULT_FG,
       bg=DEFAULT_BG,
       
     
       relief=RAISED,
       state=NORMAL).pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Checked for the performance. It works now.
Your thanks has been taken in advance.

Comment: I think `DEFAULT_BG` should be used instead of `DEFAULT_BG_HIGHLIGHT` inside `mouse_highlight_leave()`.

Comment: @acw1668, I checked with the above corrected code and it's working. By mentioning activeforeground=DEFAULT_FG and activebackground=DEFAULT_BG, he made both active and default color same. Probably His logic is: since both the fg and bg is triggered by a function, active color should be made into that of the default color. But this active color overrides the color mentioned by the function.

Comment: Your current code will change the background color to `DEFAULT_BG_HIGHLIGHT` both when moving the mouse into and out of the button.  What I mean is that the background color should be changed to `DEFAULT_BG` when the mouse is moving out of the button.

Comment: @acw1668, Yes, I don't know why I didn't see that. Now, edited my answer

Comment: I said that only the background color should be changed to `DEFAULT_BG` when the mouse is moving out of the button.